# Why won't XScreensaver install from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, screensaver

All I know is that I get the following output in my terminal:

```
supuhstar@SupuhComp-U:~$ sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xscreensaver is already the newest version.
xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod is already the newest version.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl-extra
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,369 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 195814 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xscreensaver-data-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xscreensaver-data-extra (5.15-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xscreensaver-data-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/screensavers/sonar.desktop', which is also in package xscreensaver-gl 5.15-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../xscreensaver-gl-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xscreensaver-gl-extra (5.15-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xscreensaver-gl-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/screensavers/antinspect.desktop', which is also in package xscreensaver-gl 5.15-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xscreensaver-data-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xscreensaver-gl-extra_5.15-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl* xscreensaver-data* xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod`. That includes two more packages (xscreensaver-data and xscreensaver-gl). Probably yours don't install because they miss these.

Comment: You have installed xscreensaver-gl version 5.15.3, which is not published in the ubuntu archive.  Ubuntu only has version 5.15.3-ubuntu1.  Your version contains sonar.desktop, which conflicts with the version in xscreensaver-data-extra version 5.15-3ubuntu1.  You must have installed this rogue version of xscreensaver-gl from somewhere else; possibly debian?

Comment: @psusi that sounds about right... What can I do about that?

Comment: Remove the debian package and stick with ubuntu ones.

Comment: @psusi could you elaborate on how to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands in the terminal in this order solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y -f
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod -y -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the correct ubuntu package has a newer version that the debian one you have installed, simply running an `apt-get upgrade` should take care of switching this package to the ubuntu version.  In general, you shouldn't be installing packages from debian on an ubuntu system.

Comment: This didn't work; now I get this output: http://pastebin.com/K8Q3n9dL

Comment: @Supuhstar, ahh, it tried to upgrade the other package first, which failed, then gave up instead of upgrading you out of the debian version of xscreensaver-gl.

Comment: okay... So why did my answer work?

Comment: @Supuhstar, hrm.. now that I look again I don't know.  My first thought was that you simply told apt explicitly to upgrade xscreensaver-gl rather than xscreensaver-data-extra, but looking again now that does not seem to be the case.